# Mac status bar app icon moves on click

Tags: objective-c, xcode, statusbar

When you click on the status bar icon to show the app, the icon jumps to the left until you focus on another or the window redraws, like when you activate Mission Control. I have figured out it only does this when I have the table view's 'Content View' set to 'View Based'. If I have the table view's 'Content Mode' set to 'Cell Based' it doesn't happen. See images below.

**View Based Content Mode**
[image: View Based Content Mode]

**Cell Based Content Mode**
[image: Cell Based Content Mode]

Has anyone else run into this problem? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.